# FizzBuzz in CSS

Tags: css, fizzbuzz

So someone challenged me to write FizzBuzz using CSS only. This was the best I could come up with, but I think the "divisible by 5, not divisible by 3" CSS rule is a bit clunky. So I'm looking for advice to provide a more readable and maintainable solution.

```css
ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: listCounter;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(listCounter);
}
ol li:nth-child(3n + 3):before {
  content: 'fizz';
}
ol li:nth-child(5n + 5):not(:nth-child(3n + 3)):before {
  content: '';
}
ol li:nth-child(5n + 5):after {
  content: 'buzz';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of putting `ol li:before { content: counter(listCounter); }` on every element and cancelling out some of them with `ol li:nth-child(5n + 5):not(:nth-child(3n + 3)):before { content: ''; }`, I would just show the counter on elements that need it.

I don't know why you put `+ 3` and `+ 5` in the selectors — they don't appear to be necessary.

```css
ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: listCounter;
}
ol li:not(:nth-child(3n)):not(:nth-child(5n)):before {
  content: counter(listCounter);
}
ol li:nth-child(3n):before {
  content: 'fizz';
}
ol li:nth-child(5n):after {
  content: 'buzz';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Strictly speaking, the second rule could be reduced to just

```
ol li:not(:nth-child(5n)):before {
  content: counter(listCounter);
}
```

since the following rule supersedes it in for multiples of 3.

Comment: Awesome! I forgot that `n` in `nth-child` could never be zero. The `+3` and `+5` was to prevent zero from triggering `fizzbuzz`.